# What are the requirements for a house in mobile Terraria?

Tags: terraria-mobile

[image: The "house"]

Background: I built a nice village with NPCs. I have also built a "wall" out of wooden beams and some "towers" at the side ends. After a goblin invasion, we had some casualties, so I decided to remove the houses and build an apartment kind of building.

But, I ran into another problem. I built the first floor—it worked fine, but in the second floor, none of the NPCs moved in, and that's the problem. What could be wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

[image: From my comment...]

Comment: I think it's a problem with the NPCs just not liking my house style XD

Comment: Its not about the style, but I cant tell for sure without trying myself.

Comment: OK, I have not done anything like this in my life...

Comment: Hmmm... this link is useful but I still do not understand,I did the exact same thing on my other world and it worked...

Comment: @zoddlerdrummer I have beaten the mobile version, so I have some experience playing it, and sometimes it took almost 30 minutes or so before an NPC decided he wanted to move in, despite the room being available for the entire time. Just wait, is my idea.

Comment: Ok , I'll try waiting, I will post here if it worked.

Comment: hmmmm.. I encountered something REALLY strange.

Comment: After I broke my first Shadow orb, I knew a meteor is gonna fall, so I built a stone "shield", in case a meteor falls in the village, but...it seems like their houses went higher XD